# Empty message body when sending mail using a bash script

Tags: bash, email

I have a peculiar problem that I cannot wrap my head around.

Whenever I append a variable to the file being used as the email body, the email goes out with an empty attachment.
If I do the same thing by appending static text to the file being used as the email body, the email goes out with the content of the file as the email body, as intended.

Here are the details:

The code snippet shown below works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
to_email="Actual Email Address"
from_email="Actual Email Address"
title="Sample email"
echo "Hello" >> body.txt
mail -s "$title" $to_email < body.txt
```

However, if I append a variable that I'm getting from another command, as shown below, the email goes out with an empty attachment.

```
echo "Hello" >> body.txt
echo "$variable" >> body.txt # $variable is being returned by another function
mail -s "$title" $to_email < body.txt
```

The variable is a string.
When I see the content of body.txt, it has the $variable properly appended to it.

Can someone tell why is the email going out with an empty file as email body?

Comment: you must give `body.txt` to your `mail` command and NOT put output of `mail` to `body.txt`, therefore use this in both cases: `mail -s "$title" $to_email < body.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The part that you highlighted was a typo. Apologies!
I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Is that a problem with body.txt content? Can you show us your body.txt file which is not being attached to mail?